# What event should I use to track for how long users didn’t open my app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Using firebase *default* events I'm trying to determine how long users didn't open my app.
The ultimate goal is to build audiences based on inactive users and send them engaging messages so they could reconsider using my app. (either thru cloud messaging or thru google ads)

I tried the following:

Using session_start event and event count < 1 and setting the membership duration to 7, 30, 360

would this audience accurately represent the set of users who opened my app at maximum once for a given period?

Are there better ways to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To track users that haven't recently used your app, you could indeed define multiple audiences based on how long ago the `session_start` event occurred. Then you can define "lapsed users" audience as users who have used the app at least one in the past year, and exclude users that have used the in the past week (or whatever interval you're interested in).

[image]

See the blog post [A Crash Course in Using the New Audiences in Analytics](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/01/a-crash-course-in-using-new-audiences.html). The example of "all of your app users except those in an audience" is closest to your scenario (and from where I copied the above screenshot).

Comment: The logic I used in my suggested solution won't work since the only operator that could be used with event count is "greater than" ">". so the only workaround there is as you suggested. make an audience of active users then exclude them when making a push notification. but still I won't be able to create an audience for inactive users and I can't target them for remarketing in google ads. am I right?